# Catch user authentication

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to find a way to catch the first time a user authenticate my Facebook app.
The only solution I came up with was to create a DB and track the UID (if the uid doesn't exist in the db, its a new user) but it seems like a complicated solution to a simple problem.

Do you know if theres a callback, trigger etc. that I can hook to ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example implementation with `Facebook C# SDK` and `C#`

```
            long userId = FacebookWebContext.Current.UserId;                
            User user = ... //Query from user with userId
            if (user == null)
            {
                FacebookWebClient fbWebClient = new FacebookWebClient();
                dynamic fbUser = fbWebClient.Get(userId);
                user = new Fr.Models.User
                {
                    Id = userId,
                    Name = fbUser.name,
                    FbProfileUrl = fbUser.link,
                    LoginCount = 1,
                    LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now,
                    CreateDate = DateTime.Now                        
                };                    
                //Save user to db

            }
            else
            {
                if (user.LoginCount == null)
                    user.LoginCount = 0;
                user.LoginCount = user.LoginCount + 1;
                user.LastLoginDate = DateTime.Now;
                //Update user to DB its login count & Date
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I **don't** think Facebook will send any variable to indicate first-time users. But I just can't see why having a *simple* database is considered a *complicated* solution?

*Database Driven* websites are trivial now!